# Assign existing field to new content type programmatically

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I'm developing a module that create a several new content types:

```
function create_new_content_type($type, $name){
    $t = get_t();

    $new_node = array(
        'type' => $type,
        'name' => $name,
        'base' => 'node_content',
        'custom' => TRUE,
        //'description' => 'This is an example node type with a few fields.',
    );
    $content_type = node_type_set_defaults($new_node);
    node_add_body_field($content_type);

    // Check if we create content type or update.
    $status = node_type_save($content_type);

    // Replacement rule for the messages.
    $t_args = array('%name' => $content_type->name);

    if ($status == SAVED_NEW) { // create case
        watchdog('node', 'Added content type %name.', $t_args, WATCHDOG_NOTICE, l($t('view'), 'admin/structure/types'));
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

after that creates a new fields for that type (for example):

```
function createTextField($name, $label, $bundle, $required=FALSE){
    // Create the field base.
    $field = array(
        'field_name' => $name,
        'type' => 'text',
    );
    field_create_field($field);

    // Create the field instance on the bundle.
    $instance = array(
        'field_name' => $name,
        'entity_type' => 'node',
        'label' => $label,
        'bundle' => $bundle,
        // If you don't set the "required" property then the field wont be required by default.
        'required' => $required,
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
        ),
    );
    field_create_instance($instance);

}
```

Lets assume I have already existed field with name `field_my_custom` how can I attach it to my new created content type? (if I understand right in the method above I only create new fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call again the `field_create_instance()` function passing a new array.

```
 $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_my_custom', // ** This already exists, or check with field_info_field()
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'label' => 'a label', // change this of course
    'bundle' => $new_created_content_type, // this too 
    'widget' => array(), // if you're not sure about your widget settings, take a glimpse at an existing field instance using debug(field_info_instance(...));
);
field_create_instance($instance);
```

More links to read and better understand the above functions:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7

Also, take a look at the [Examples for Developers](https://drupal.org/project/examples) module, node example and field example.

Answer (score 1):

No creating a new instance means you are attaching that field to a content type. Here $bundle is the machine name of the content type

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function new_menu(){
    $items = array();

 $items['field_create'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'field_create',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access callback' => TRUE,
      );

return $items;

}



function field_create() {



/*print_r(field_info_field($myField_name));
exit;*/

$contenttypes = node_type_get_types();


foreach($contenttypes as $type)
{

     $myField_name = "new_".$type->type."_value9";

    if(!field_info_field($myField_name)) 
    {


    /*print_r($type);
    exit;*/ 



    $field = array(
        'field_name'    => $myField_name,
        'type'          => 'image',
    );
    field_create_field($field);

    $field_instance = array(
        'field_name'    => $myField_name,
        'entity_type'   => 'node',
        'bundle'        => 'Basic Page',
        'label'         => t('Select an image'),
        'description'   => t(''),
        'widget'        => array(
            'type'      => 'image_image',
            'weight'    => 10,
        ),
        'formatter'     => array(
            'label'     => t('label'),
            'format'    => 'image'
        ),
        'settings'      => array(
            'file_directory'        => 'gallery', 
            'max_filesize'          => '4M',
            'preview_image_style'   => 'thumbnail',
            'title_field'           => TRUE,
            'alt_field'             => FALSE,
        )
    );
    field_create_instance($field_instance);

}
 }
 drupal_set_message("Field created successfully!");

}
```

Comment: please add some description to your answer.